# Cannot configure wlan0 with static ip?

Tags: debian, arm, wlan

Debian Wheezy on ARM: wlan0 works with DHCP but doesn't work with static IP.

This is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
iface wlan0 inet static
    wpa-ssid "mySSID"
    wpa-psk "myPASS"
address 10.1.30.33
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 10.1.1.1
```

But it doesn't work: I get the interface listed with ifconfig, but I cannot ping anything (nor I cannot be pinged). If I set inet dhcp everything works...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does pinging 8.8.8.8 work?

Comment: No it doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to consider here:

- What's the output of **route** command? There should be a
  "default" destination listed.
- **cat /etc/resolv.conf** should have
  at least one address in it. mine is 127.0.0.1 but can be your routers
  address or others.
- Are you actually connected to a router? try **iwgetid** I believe that shows the connected BSSID or nothing if not connected.

Alternatively you could set up a reserved DHCP address on your router so it uses DHCP but you're address is fixed.

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wlan0

Comment: After a while, the network is working... not sure if it has something to do with the commands suggested that I've issued.

Comment: Those commands are just looking at settings. I forgot to ask if you could actually ping your gateway IP, because that's the biggest sign that nothing is connected. **ifconfig wlan0 down** then **ifconfig wlan0 up** is also useful for reinitialising the interface config. Good it sorted itself anyway!